# Fill out html table from a loop

Tags: css

I have a list of elements, which I render from cshtml:

```
<div class="col-xs-9">
foreach (var item in MyCollection)
{
    <span>item</span>
}
</div>
```

This results in rows:

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

How can I get layout in columns? Like this:

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

I would like to stack elements by three and then start a new column.
Count of items in MyCollection can differ. 
For instance, if there are four elements, would like to see:

```
1 4
2
3
```

Comment: Kindly provide the complete code you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS `column-count` class helped:
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/column-count.